# DBpedia Spotlight on my own instance

Tags: python, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I have set up my own instance of dbpedia on an Amazon EC2 instance: http://xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I had written code that access DBpedia like so:

```
annotations = spotlight.annotate('http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate', document, confidence=0.4, support=20)
```

where "document" is some string. How do I take what I have down previously and use it on my own instance?

I have tried to replace `http://spotlight/dbpedia.org/rest/annotate` with `http://xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/rest/annotate`, but this is incorrect.

Any assistance would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a command line like

java -jar dbpedia-spotlight.jar /data/spotlight/en/model_en http://[your_amazon_server]:2222/rest

the service is available at http://[your_amazon_server]:2222/rest/annotate.

(notice the port number 2222) Also, make sure there is no firewall blocking that port (AWS: SecurityGroups -> Inbound).

We have more information at https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Installation.

All the best,